# Writing your first Django app, part 5 error import models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I’m doing the first django application tutorial, I’m in part 05 and I’m having problems with “tests.py”, when I run “python manage.py test polls”, it returns the following error message:

“RuntimeError: Model class mysite.polls.models.Question doesn’t declare an explicit app_label and isn’t in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.”

However, ‘polls.apps.PollsConfig’ has already been added to INSTALLED_APPS, and the error continues to appear.

I started “from polls.models import Question”, I managed to start the entire test through the shell, but in tests.py it gives this error

I want the error to go away so I can run the necessary tests and continue the django tutorial

Comment: Can u try by removing db.sqlite3 and again perform the migrations process of polls model.

Comment: I just tried, it didn't work :(

Comment: What you need to add to `INSTALLED_APPS` is the name of your app (your app label). If you are following the tutorial to the letter then its called `polls`.